# How to draw rectangular boxes with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-node

I want to draw rectangular box around some text, and use arrows to point from one of them to the other. But, one text is a bit longer, so I also want to split it into to lines. I have the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
        One side

        \begin{tikzpicture}[rectangle,draw=cyan,thick]

            \node (pq1) {Hard problems};
            \node [dashed,below=of pq1] (pq2) {Construct new problems};
            \node [below=of pq2] (pq3) {Framework fail};
            \node [dashed,below=of pq3] (pq4) {Analyze against \\new adversaries};

            \path[->,thick,cyan] (pq1) edge  (pq2)
                                 (pq3) edge  (pq4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
        Other Part
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The point is that only the arrows are drawn, but rectangles are not drawn around the text. I want two of them to be with solid lines, the other two with dashed lines. Also how can I split the text into to lines in TikZ node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

For node you need define option `align` and in your case I suggest also `text width=...`. I assume, that the shapes of all nodes are the same, so I define a common style for all:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
        One side
\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {shape=rectangle,% is not necessary, default node's shape is rectangle
                     draw=cyan, semithick,
                     text width=0.8\linewidth,
                     align=center}
                            ]
\node (pq1) [draw] {Hard problems};
\node (pq2) [dashed,below=of pq1] {Construct new problems};
\node (pq3) [below=of pq2] {Framework fail};
\node (pq4) [dashed,below=of pq3] {Analyze against \\new adversaries};
%
\path[->,thick,cyan] (pq1) edge  (pq2)
                     (pq3) edge  (pq4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.50\textwidth}
        Other Part
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you like to have diferent nodes shape width, accomodate to contained text, than delete option `text width=...` in definition for `every node`.